# Menu item added with "wp_nav_menu_items" gives "damaged" url

Tags: menus

I am adding menu items with the code below, the menu items show up when clicked but they give **damaged** url's

e.g for the top link when clicked

```
http://timothylhanson.com/bp/%3C?php%20return%20bp_loggedin_user_domain()%20?%3Eactivity/just-me/
```

clearly this

```
<?php return bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>
```

is not being returned properly

Any help with this is greatly appreciated
Thanks

```
function add_profile_link_to_nav($items) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )

return $items . 
 '<li class="myclass"><a href="<?php return bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>activity/just-me/">My Wall</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">

 <li class="menu-item"><a href="<?php return bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>activity/friends/">My Friends Activities</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item"> <a href="<?php return bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>profile/edit/group/1">Edit My Profile</a></li>

</ul>
 </li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_profile_link_to_nav', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<?php return bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>` is part of a string therefor it is not executed. You should probably have

```
'<li class="myclass"><a href="'. bp_loggedin_user_domain() .'activity/just-me/">My Wall</a> ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, very grateful for your help.